# can't we use same variable name as a function?

Tags: c, variables, pointers

Here my code..it is giving segmentation fault error...please tell me why...In this small program i am taking one function add() and one variable int add. and inside the main function i am creating a function pointer of add() and trying to print the value of add variable. But it is giving error...plz tell me why??

```
#include<stdio.h>
float add(int , float);
int main()
{
        float (*fp)(int , float);
        float result;
        int add=10;
        fp = add;
        result = fp(5 , 9.9);
        printf("%f\n",result);
        printf("%d\n",add);
        return 0;

}

float add(int a ,float b)
{
        return a + b;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you write: `fp = add; int add = 10;`, i.e. assign function to pointer before declaring `add` variable.

Comment: I think you should respect the warnings complier throw at you .. When you assign `fp = add` , any reasonable compiler throws a warning about incompatible assignments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Global names are [shadowed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) by local names.**

So, when you mention `add` in `main`, it will always try to take `add` that is declared in `main` first.

When you are giving `fp = add` you are assigning an integer (`int add = 10`) to a function pointer. and trying to call to the address. This is an invalid address (`10`), so you got the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Function names can be seen as global constant pointers to functions, basically.

Your

```
int add = 10;
```

[shadows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the definition of the `add()` function, causing your function pointer to be set to `10` interpreted as a function pointer, which is bad.

Answer (score 2):

The code you've written doesn't have the effect you expect. When you declare the int variable `add` it shadows the function. After that this code `fp=add` actually assigns the function pointer to the value of the integer variable add. Then when you call the function pointed to by `fp`, you access some weird address( nameley `10`) and get a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Function `add()` a global variable and  `int add` is local variable when you try to assign add to a pointer the scope of local variable prevails over global.

Try to read the warning it would say something like type mismatch for that.

If you are using gcc type `gcc -Wall programname.c`